# Serious mountain business only. Bring your gear

Tags: word, knowledge, geography

> Half a mountain,
>   a man who made a film about a mountain,
>   a man who wrote a book about a mountain,
>   half a mountain,
>   something resembling a mountain.

Looking for the name of a... yeah, you guessed it.

Hint:

> It's a big one.

Comment: are you looking for a specific mountain?

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid yes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for:

> [**KANGCHENJUNGA**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangchenjunga)

Half a mountain,

> **K** is the first half of [K2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K2).

a man who made a film about a mountain,

> [**ANG** Lee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ang_Lee) directed *Brokeback Mountain*.

a man who wrote a book about a mountain,

> [Da **CHEN**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Da_Chen) wrote *Colors of the Mountain*.

half a mountain,

> **JUNG** is the first half of [Jungfrau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jungfrau).

something resembling a mountain.

> The capital letter **A** looks like a mountain.

Comment: yap, that actually makes sense, was unclear about the hints at first...

Comment: That is it. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

is it-

> Everest

Reasoning

> It is the highest mountain, there have been lots of books and movies about Everest